# How can I change mousewheel behaviour in PyQtGraph ImageView?

Tags: python, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I am using ImageView to display 2D slices of a 3D volume (MRI scan data) and would like to change the mouse bindings to be more intuitive to the user.  By default the mouse wheel changes the image scale/zoom.  Instead, **I would like the wheel to change to the next/previous slice** - to move forward or backward along the series of 2D images that make up the 3D volume.  The documentation uses the z-axis as time - so there it would be moving forward / backwards in time.

I don't see any easy pyqtgraph mouse event methods to reimplement, nor can I see how to do this in PySide2.  There seem to be hints in this virtual function [grabMouseEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QGraphicsWidget.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsWidget.grabMouseEvent) but I do not know how to reimplement to capture the wheel.

This is my minimal working code to create my window and 50 frames of 100x100 pixel noise data:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout

import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.cw = QWidget(self)
        self.cw.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cw.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.DcmImgWidget = MyImageWidget(parent=self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.DcmImgWidget)

        self.show()


class MyImageWidget(pg.ImageView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self._parent = parent
        self.ui.histogram.hide()
        self.ui.roiBtn.hide()
        self.ui.menuBtn.hide()

        # 50 frames of 100x100 random noise
        img = np.random.normal(size=(50, 100, 100))
        self.setImage(img)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It scrolls very nicely using the scrollbar below the image.

How can I reimplement the mouse wheel events within PyQtGraph objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to intercept the wheel event of the GraphicsView through an event filter and prevent the event from being transmitted, then use the event information to emit a signal that indicates whether to go to a next page or a previous one.

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QEvent, Signal
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
)

import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.DcmImgWidget = MyImageWidget()

        self.cw = QWidget()
        self.cw.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.cw)
        layout.addWidget(self.DcmImgWidget)


class Helper(QObject):
    changed = Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.widget and event.type() == QEvent.Wheel:
            self.changed.emit(event.angleDelta().y() > 0)
            return True

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class MyImageWidget(pg.ImageView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui.histogram.hide()
        self.ui.roiBtn.hide()
        self.ui.menuBtn.hide()

        # 50 frames of 100x100 random noise
        img = np.random.normal(size=(50, 100, 100))
        self.setImage(img)

        gv = self.ui.graphicsView
        helper = Helper(gv.viewport())
        helper.changed.connect(self.change_page)

    def change_page(self, state):
        self.jumpFrames(1 if state else -1)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to see what you did there- Let me check my understanding- the helper function creates a new signal 'changed' which is used when a mouse wheel event arrives in 'eventFilter'. The 'self.changed.emit' then passes the bool result of '(event.angleDelta().y() > 0)' as the argument to the connected 'change_page' method.  So to capture and handle mouse clicks & drags I assume that I should make a new signal, eventFilter  conditions and corresponding slot method in 'MyImageWidget'...?